# Django - get Foreign Key first object in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I can't get the Foreign Key first object without looping all foreign keys.
I'm using Django `1.10.5`.

I have these models:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    ...

class Message(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, related_name='messages')
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

And then in the template (DetailView of Ticket) I do:

```
<p>{{ object.messages.all|first }}</p>
<p>{{ object.messages.all.0 }}</p>
<p>{{ object.messages.all.1}}</p>
{% for message in object.messages.all %}
    <p>{{ message}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

And this prints in the template:

```
2
2
2
1
2
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
{{ object.messages.first }}
```

Comment: It works (thanks!) but I don't understand why mine doesn't. I will not accept (yet) to see if someone can enlight me.

Comment: Possible because object.messages.all is QuerySet